# XSLT to find lowest price

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

i am beginner in XSLT and using to transform XML to XML.

I require to get `Prices` tag which has lowest sum.

**Source XML:**

```
<Result>
    <Fares>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="15"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="10"/>
            <Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="10"/>
            <Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
            <Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
            <Prices>
        </Fare>
    </Fares>
</Result>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Result">
        <xsl:element name="Lowest">
            <xsl:variable name="lowest" select="Fares/Fare/Prices[not(sum(Price/@ticket) &gt; //Fares/Fare/Prices[sum(Price/@ticket)])]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$lowest"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<Lowest>
    <Prices>
        <Price type="adt" ticket="15"/>
        <Price type="chd" ticket="10"/>
        <Price type="inf" ticket="10"/>
    <Prices/>
    </Prices>
</Lowest>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<Lowest>
    <Prices Total="15">
        <Price type="adt" ticket="5"/>
        <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
        <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
    <Prices>
</Lowest>
```

As shown above output should have the `Prices` tag with lowest value as attribute also.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, could you share your XSLT code..? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure the XSLT you're showing actually gives the output that you say it does? For me, using Saxon 6.5.5, it gives different output: it outputs all four `<Prices>` elements with their descendants.

Comment: @LarsH - i am using java to transform XML to XML and engine is JAXP (default one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/Fare">
       <xsl:sort select="sum(Prices/Price/@ticket)" data-type="number"/>

       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
         <Lowest Total="{sum(Prices/Price/@ticket)}">
           <xsl:copy-of select="Prices"/>
         </Lowest>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (with several malformities corrected!!!):**

```
<Result>
    <Fares>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="15"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="10"/>
            </Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="10"/>
            </Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
            </Prices>
        </Fare>
        <Fare>
            <Prices>
                <Price type="adt" ticket="10"/>
                <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
                <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
            </Prices>
        </Fare>
    </Fares>
</Result>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Lowest Total="15">
   <Prices>
      <Price type="adt" ticket="5"/>
      <Price type="chd" ticket="5"/>
      <Price type="inf" ticket="5"/>
   </Prices>
</Lowest>
```

Comment: Dimitre, the OP wants to add a `Total` attribute to the `<Prices>` element. BTW, it would be helpful to add an explanation of why the OP's original XPath expression doesn't work, so we have to use for-each with sort. Something to do with the limitations of `sum()` in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort and take the one that is first in sort order:

```
<xsl:template match="Result">
  <Lowest>
    <xsl:for-each select="Fares/Fare/Prices">
      <xsl:sort select="sum(Price/@ticket)" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
         <Prices Total="{sum(Price/@ticket)}">
           <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
         </Prices>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Lowest>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think you mean `{sum(Price/@ticket)}`.

Comment: @Martin - i have tried that but got the first `Prices` tag with value of `Total` 35.

Comment: Lars is right, I used the wrong `sum` expression, I will correct that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing your `<Prices>` tags!

But this should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Lowest>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Result/Fares/Fare/Prices">
        <xsl:sort select="sum(./Price/@ticket)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <Prices>
            <xsl:attribute name="Total">
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(./Price/@ticket)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./Price"/>
          </Prices>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Lowest>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using this solution i got `<Price Total="0"/>`.

Comment: what are you developing this in then? I used the Visual Studio 2010 XSLT debugger and got the correct result...

Comment: make sure you've fixed the closing <Prices> tags!

Comment: @Ankur: warning, that purplegene.com page uses whatever XSLT processor is available *in the browser*. Not all browser-provided XSLT processors adhere to the standard. If you need your stylesheet to work in a particular browser, best to say which browser you're using.